# How to get the description of column name in tibble?

Tags: r

In R, I am using `qualtRics` package to read my Qualitrics data using  which uses `sjlabelled` to set labels.

How do I get "What would you.." in the following image?

[image]

Here is the output for `print`:

```
> print(raw$QA1)
[1] "Red and black" "Red and black" "Red and black" "Red and black"
[5] "Red and black" "Red and black" NA              NA             
[9] NA             
attr(,"label")
                             QA1 
"What's the color of the robot?"
```

---

Edit: I tried `attr` function:

```
> print(attr(raw$QA1, "label"))
                             QA1 
"What's the color of the robot?"
```

Comment: `attr(raw$QA1, "label")`?

Comment: @r2evans it still has QA1... See my update

Comment: `unname(attr(raw$QA1, "label"))`? The `character` vector you get from the `attr(...)` call is named, but can still be handled like an un-named character vector. The name is just a "bonus".\

Comment: Thanks, @r2evans! Would you like to make you last comment an answer so I can mark it accepted?

Comment: The `sjlabelled` package also has a generic function `get_label` which you can use, e.g. `get_label(raw$QA1)`

Comment: @DiceboyT I used that function but it didn't give me the label of the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the attribute itself, use

```r
attr(raw$QA1, "label")
```

This will get you a *named* `character` vector, and while you can use that just fine in anything that expects a string, if you prefer to remove the name (for console aesthetics), then you can use the `unname` function as well:

```r
unname(attr(raw$QA1, "label"))
```